# hyperref pointing to the wrong equation using subequations

Tags: hyperref, subequations

I'm using the following code to write an article, but I'm having some problems cross-referencing the equations with `hyperref`.

The `\eqref{}` code returns the right equation's number. But the hyperlinks of the first and second `\eqref{}` point to equations (1) and (2), and not to correct equations (3a) and (3b), inside the `\begin{subequations}` ambient. Last `\eqref{}` instead works correctly. What is wrong with this code?

Thank you for the help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A=B
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B=C
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
C=D
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D=E
\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\begin{equation}
E=F
\label{eq:3}
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq:1} \eqref{eq:2} \eqref{eq:3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: i'm not familiar with `pdfx`, but it presumably takes the place of `hyperref`.  it is, with very few exceptions, necessary for `hyperref` to be called last.  you have `pdfx` first.

Comment: `pdfx` does not work on my system, removing it, anding `hyperref` and placing `hyperref` + `\hypersetup` last, then I see no problems with the hyperlink targets.

Comment: Calling `pdfx` and `\hypersetup` last works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wanna make that an answer?

Answer (score 4):

i'm not familiar with `pdfx`, but it presumably takes the place of `hyperref`.

it is, with very few exceptions, necessary for `hyperref` to be called last.

you have `pdfx` first.