# Command eqref links to incorrect equation but shows correct numbering

Tags: equations, hyperref, eqref

I am trying to reference to an element inside an `align` environment inside a `subequations` environment. The reference number using is shown correctly by the
`eqref` command, but when clicked points to the incorrect equation. I report a minimal sample that reproduces the problem, and I would love some help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}


\begin{document}
First NLP
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:opt_00}
\begin{align}
   &\min_{\bm{x}} J(\bm{x}) \\
   &\text{subject to:} \nonumber \\
    &\bm{x}_{min} \le \bm{x} \le \bm{x}_{max} \label{eq:opt_kin_bounds}\\
    &\textit{some constraint on } \bm{x} \label{eq:opt_kin_ballistic}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Then another NLP
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:opt_0}
\begin{align}
   &\min_{\bm{w}} J(\bm{w}) \\
    &\text{subject to:} \nonumber \\
    &\bm{x}_{i+1}-\bm{\phi}^L_{d\text{-}t}(\bm{x}_i,\bm{u}_i)=\ \bm{0} \quad i=0 \hdots N-1 \label{eq:opt_0_dynamics} \\
    &\bm{x}_0-\bm{x}_{init}= \ \bm{0} \label{eq:opt_0_xinit}\\
    &\bm{x}_N - \bm{x}_{th}=\bm{0} \label{eq:opt_0_xthrow}\\
    &\bm{x}_{min} \le \bm{x}_i \le \bm{x}_{max} \quad i=0 \hdots N \label{eq:opt_0_xbound}\\
    &\bm{u}_{min} \le \bm{u}_i \le \bm{u}_{max} \quad i=0 \hdots N-1 \label{eq:opt_0_ubound}\\
    &\textit{some constraints at } i=0 \hdots N \label{eq:opt_0_bal}.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Ref to the constraints \eqref{eq:opt_0_dynamics}, \eqref{eq:opt_0_xinit} are wrong, but \eqref{eq:opt_0_xthrow}, \eqref{eq:opt_0_xbound}, \eqref{eq:opt_0_ubound}, and \eqref{eq:opt_0_bal} are correct.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just to put `\usepackage{hyperref}` as last package to include, as replied in [hyperref pointing to the wrong equation using subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217679/hyperref-pointing-to-the-wrong-equation-using-subequations)
I will leave this here if someone else needs this in the future